Snowflake unsupported subquery type for UDTF
In Snowflake, I'm trying to save a large amount of code size and maintenance by creating a UDTF to show flags for each row v based on presence of rows in x or y meeting some pattern.
The error I get is SQL Error [2031] [42601]: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
Here's some minimal example code:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS v;
CREATE TABLE v (CHARTGUID NUMBER(16));
INSERT INTO v VALUES(1410522400170);
INSERT INTO v VALUES(1548089000170);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
CREATE TABLE x (CHARTGUID NUMBER(16), FOO INT, BAR VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO x(CHARTGUID, FOO, BAR) VALUES (1410522400170, 1, 'a');
INSERT INTO x(CHARTGUID, FOO, BAR) VALUES (1548089000170, 0, 'a');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS y;
CREATE TABLE y (CHARTGUID NUMBER(16), FOO INT, BAR VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO y(CHARTGUID, FOO, BAR) VALUES (1410522400170, 0, 'a');
INSERT INTO y(CHARTGUID, FOO, BAR) VALUES (1548089000170, 1, 'a');
INSERT INTO y(CHARTGUID, FOO, BAR) VALUES (1548089000170, 1, 'b');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_C(CHART_GUID NUMBER, p VARCHAR)
   RETURNS TABLE(A INT, B INT)
AS
$$
   SELECT
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT x.CHARTGUID
         FROM x
         WHERE x.CHARTGUID = CHART_GUID
            AND x.FOO = 1
            AND x.BAR = p
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT y.CHARTGUID
         FROM y
         WHERE y.CHARTGUID = CHART_GUID
            AND y.FOO = 1
            AND y.BAR = p
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
$$
;

SELECT
   v.CHARTGUID,
   x.*
FROM v,
   TABLE(TEST_C(v.CHARTGUID, 'a')) x

The true use case has many TABLE(TEST_C(v.CHARTGUID, 'a')), where 'a' is a regex pattern and its presence in the two tables x and y needs to be checked for each pattern.
I want to avoid this sort of pattern:
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT x.CHARTGUID
      FROM x
      WHERE x.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND x.BAR LIKE 'a%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Ax",
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT y.CHARTGUID
      FROM y
      WHERE y.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND y.BAR LIKE 'a%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Ay",
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT x.CHARTGUID
      FROM x
      WHERE x.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND x.BAR LIKE 'b%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Bx",
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT y.CHARTGUID
      FROM y
      WHERE y.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND y.BAR LIKE 'b%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "By",
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT x.CHARTGUID
      FROM x
      WHERE x.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND x.BAR LIKE 'c%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Cx",
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT y.CHARTGUID
      FROM y
      WHERE y.CHARTGUID = v.CHARTGUID
         AND y.BAR LIKE 'c%'
   ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "Cy",
   -- etc...
FROM v

What's the workaround for snowflakes 'subquery limitation'?

The short answer is, you are trying to "save code time/space" in trade off for bad performance. So the SQL compiler is telling you, "I am sorry this is bad, I am not going to do this for you" So you are ether looking for a work-around "that is good SQL/performance" or "bad SQL performance that allows your SQL to be lazy" which one are you interested in? This is not to say "this is not valid SQL" it's just not simple to do effectively across billions of rows, without knowing a lot more about the data. That you the engineer most likey do/should know.

So the tables can be written differently, that I feel is cleaner as there are less characters, thus it's more readable, and they are atomic operations:
CREATE or replace TABLE v (CHARTGUID number) 
    as select * from values
        (1410522400170),
        (1548089000170);

CREATE or replace TABLE x (CHARTGUID number, FOO number, BAR text)
    as select * from values
        (1410522400170, 1, 'a'),
        (1548089000170, 0, 'a');

CREATE or replace TABLE y (CHARTGUID number, FOO number, BAR text)
    as select * from values
        (1410522400170, 0, 'a'),
        (1548089000170, 1, 'a'),
        (1548089000170, 1, 'b');

I would be inclined to pre-process the data so it can be equi join base (left or normal) with CTE's
WITH xx as (
    select distinct chartguid, bar
    from x 
    where foo = 1
), yy as (
    select distinct chartguid, bar
    from y
    where foo = 1
)
SELECT
   v.chartguid,
   NVL2(xx.chartguid, 1,0) as x1,
   NVL2(yy.chartguid, 1,0) as x2
FROM v
LEFT JOIN xx 
    on xx.chartguid = v.chartguid 
        and xx.bar = 'a'
LEFT JOIN yy
    on yy.chartguid = v.chartguid
        and xx.bar = 'a'

This does not give you "one clever function to hide all the workings" which is generally a gross trick, but if you need clever, you could make a UDTF that joins those two+ CTE's together before join the main table, but this might do way too much work.

With the extended case I would more likely write it like:
WITH xx as (
    select 
        chartguid, 
        count_if(bar LIKE 'a%') as "Ax",
        count_if(bar LIKE 'b%') as "Bx",
        count_if(bar LIKE 'c%') as "Cx",
    from x 
    group by 1
), yy as (
    select 
        chartguid,
        count_if(bar LIKE 'a%') as "Ay",
        count_if(bar LIKE 'b%') as "By",
        count_if(bar LIKE 'c%') as "Cy",
    from y
    group by 1
)
SELECT
   v.chartguid,
   xx.* exclude(chartguid),
   yy.* exclude(chartguid)
FROM v
LEFT JOIN xx 
    on xx.chartguid = v.chartguid 
LEFT JOIN yy
    on yy.chartguid = v.chartguid

Depending on how your tables are shaped, it might be faster to pre-join to avoid agregating unneed rows from x and y, or it might be way slower.

Is the 'a' conditional still a part of that? That's the main thing that will differ many times over

haha, I missed that.. please hold.

I've edited my original question to show what my original approach was and why I'm trying a cleaner approach. Assume that BAR are short phrases and I'm running either LIKE or RLIKE to select for them

I didn't know COUNT_IF existed.. thank you

given it can go above 1 I would beinclined to in real usage IFF(yy.ay>0,1,0) as ay to limit to always 1 or 0
